# Intellij Idea plugin: What's the method call to Resolve a Kotlin reference

Tags: kotlin, intellij-plugin

I'm writing an Intellij plugin in Kotlin for Java and Kotlin files.
The following code works for Java files:

```
val node: ASTNode
....
val referencedFieldElement = node.psi.reference!!.resolve()
```

But it doesn't work for Kotlin files because there is no resolve() method call and node.psi.reference returns null.

How do you resolve a Kotlin reference ?

Also I have a `PsiElement` Kotlin reference. How can I resolve it's value ?

Here is some code:

```
class KotlinFoldingBuilder : FoldingBuilderEx() {

    override fun buildFoldRegions(root: PsiElement, document: Document, quick: Boolean): Array<FoldingDescriptor> {
        ....
    }

    override fun getPlaceholderText(node: ASTNode): String? {
        val referencedFieldElement = node.psi.reference!!.resolve()
        return referencedFieldElement
    }

    override fun isCollapsedByDefault(node: ASTNode): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}
```

`node.psi.reference!!.resolve()` works for Java file but for Kotlin files `node.psi.reference` returns null.

A potential answer to this question can be found here https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000795610-What-s-the-methed-call-to-Resolve-a-Kotlin-reference

Comment: On which node are you calling this? There are most definitely nodes in the Kotlin PSI that do have references, and those references can be resolved using the regular resolve() method.

Comment: @yole I've added some more code and explanation. Please see the updated question. I tried calling reference on everything. It's always null. Maybe there is some different way to get the referenced value in Kotlin ? I can't even find an example.

Comment: Look, not all PsiElements have a reference! Assume you have a PsiElement that represents a simple number that this will certainly not have a reference connected to it. Simply calling `node.psi.reference!!` is evil. Check if the PsiElement actually has a reference and if yes, you might be able to resolve it.

Comment: I get what you're suggesting but I tried to call the resolve on a KtDotReference which is a static reference to a field (Ex: Math.PI) and calling reference() returns null. I also tried calling it on some different Kotlin reference types and all of them return null or some strange result. It's not straightforward like the Java ones.